# maintaining two different layout in angularjs mvc application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application with AngularJS (1.5) version. I want to maintain two different layout one before login and one after login. How Can I achieve that ?

E.g Lets say on Login I want to show different Layout/Form .. but after successful login, user redirects to different layout which will be same for rest of pages.

As I am working on MVC so I have to put code either `View/Shared/_Layout` or any default controller eg. `Views/Home/Index` .. but How can I maintain  two different layout?

Angular routing will be like this

```
var angularFormsApp = angular.module("angularFormsApp", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap"]);

angularFormsApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.caseInsensitiveMatch = true;
        $routeProvider
            .when("/account/index", {
                title: "Login",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL+"app/Login/loginTemplate.html",
                controller: "loginController"
            })
            .when("/forgotpasswordform", {
                title: "Forgot Password",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL + "app/Login/forgotPasswordFormtemplate.html",
                controller: "loginController"
            })
            .when("/forgotpasswordconfirmation", {
                title: "Forgot Password",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL + "app/Login/forgotPassConfirmationTemplate.html",
                controller: "loginController"
            })
            .when("/ResetPassword/:paramhash", {
                title: "Reset Password",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL + "app/ResetPassword/resetpasswordTemplate.html",
                controller: "ResetPassController"
            })
            .when("/Registeruser", {
                title: "New External User Setup",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL + "app/RegisterUser/registeruserTemplate.html",
                controller: "RegisterUserController"
            })
            .when("/Manageuser/", {
                title: "Manage Users",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL + "app/ManageUsers/manageUsersTemplate.html",
                controller: "manageUsersController"
            })
            .when("/changepassword/", {
                title: "Change Password",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL + "app/ChangePassword/changePasswordTemplate.html",
                controller: "changePasswordController"
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/account/index" });



    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe store information in template that the user is logged and then pass it to the rootScope like `<script>var username='<?php echo $username;?>';</script>`
and then before setting up routes check global variable `username`
if it is not empty take some other templates

another way is to use `ng-if` somewhere in the template where you want other css or html to be present like `<div ng-if="username"></div>`

if you want only redirect after successful login you can either redirect by your router or just show another content using `ng-if`

if your layouts are complicated and somehow big enough then use ng-include and make one file decide what to show while not integrating in your html schema

you must tell somehow your app that now we are displaying this and now something else, it can be by server or client side of your code, it depends on your architecture

Comment: I know about about ng-if but that's something not architectural approach...   there should be some other way to achieve this functionality

Comment: maybe redirect with some post data to figureout which content must be shown? i don't really understand why ng-if is not suitable for you, if you want same page contiain other data then maybe change it by the server side